# How can I cast a collection with generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Given the following code:

```
interface IParam {}

class Parameter implements IParam {}

void foo(Collection<? extends IParam> params) {
    SortedSet<? extends IParam> sortedParams;
    if (params instanceof SortedSet)
        sortedParams = (SortedSet<? extends IParam>) params;
    else
        sortedParams = new TreeSet<IParam>(params);
}
```

What I get is some collection of parameters.
What I need is a SortedSet of the parameters.
If the given collection already is a SortedSet, I want to use that.
Otherwise, I'll create a new TreeSet with just the content of the given collection.

However, this code doesn't compile with warnings about unchecked casts.

Is there any way to achieve what I want, without suppressing warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiles just fine for me. I would restructure the code slightly though to make it easier to conceptualize and maintain:

```
protected <T extends IParam> void foo(Collection<T> params) {
    SortedSet<T> sortedParams;
    if (params instanceof SortedSet)
        sortedParams = (SortedSet<T>) params;
    else
        sortedParams = new TreeSet<T>(params);

    System.out.println(sortedParams);
}
```

As an aside, checking for `instanceof` within a method, though not illegal, is sometimes a sign of *code smell*. Your method can be refactored with some overloading:

```
protected <T extends IParam> void foo(SortedSet<T> params) {
    System.out.println("Doing something with sorted set);
}

protected <T extends IParam> void foo(Collection<T> params) {
    SortedSet<T> sortedParams = new TreeSet<T>(params);
    System.out.println("Doing something with other collection types");
    foo(sortedParams);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this code compilable by adding two things:

- Your method `foo` needs to be in a class. Java does not allow the existence of methods outside of classes.
- Missing `;` on lines 8 and 10. Semicolons are mandatory in Java.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I'm only using conceptual code here.